# (iOS)Launching app from the same app using URLSchemes

Tags: ios

From this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) it is possible to send data/launch other apps from our app. I was just wondering if there is a way using `URLSchemes` to launch our own app when notification occurs or some other kind of trigger.

Comment: You want to launch your own app or any other? Because launching app from Push notifications happen automatically

Comment: Is it possible to auto launch app when push notification is received without user tapping on it

Comment: There are [silent push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1) (see also link in my answer), but those basically require your app to have been launched by the user and be in the background. Note the warning about misusing them for background awareness, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register your own URL scheme so that other apps can launch your app, yes. This means they need to know about your scheme and implement it accordingly, though.

You cannot use a URL scheme to have a notification launch your app. There are limited ways for having your app launched besides the user tapping its icon (or re-opening it via the task manager). [Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/) are in general a way to "trigger" your app launch, but only under certain conditions (that ultimately depend on your apps defined capabilities). Usually that requires user interaction as well, though: iOS first shows the notification on screen and only if the user taps that accordingly your app is launched.

Certain other events also launch your app, usually into the background if it's needed (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23)). VoIP apps or location-tracking apps make use of this.

In general, though, you don't get any automated, easy, way to launch your app, that's a core design principle on iOS.

---

In general: Be wary of what "launching" and "background" mean under iOS. The system tries to keep up the illusion that the user is always in control and manages what is and what is not active in any way. If you are fine with being in the background (i.e. suspended) and want to be "launched" from there, silent push notifications can be your thing, though they're not necessarily guaranteed to arrive immediately [1]. The part most devs don't understand here is that this *can* mean you are technically really launched, as in your app's process wasn't running before and is started. This happens e.g. after a device reboot: Since iOS tries to hide any technicalities from the user, to them it still looks like the app is suspended (i.e. it's in the task manager). It will behave as such. While technically this results in your app being launched, it's more the illusion os *resuming* activity from the user's perspective. Since they never explicitly terminated your app, it is just "there". Correspondingly, if they *do* terminate your app, iOS *won't* launch your app again when a silent push notification arrives (IIRC VoIP apps are an exception here) or when a location update happens.

To summarize: You can't circumvent user interactions regarding starting or terminating your app. It will only ever be "autostarted" if it makes sense *from the user's perspective*, and that perspective is usually agnostic to actual process states of apps. Using silent push notifications to update your app in the background might be what you're after.

[1]: An exception are said VoIP apps. They basically also use silent push notifications to wake your app, but those have high priority. Apple review doesn't allow "fake" VoIP apps, though, so don't try to trick your way into this if you're not an app meant for calls. :)

Comment: So there is no way to launch the app from background without user interaction?

Comment: No, not really. As I said, there are certain exceptions, but those exist more as a consequence of certain usage scenarios. For example VoIP apps are started (if they're not already running) when a push notification indicating an incoming call arrives, but that's an exception. Same goes for apps that track location in the background after a device reboot: They're (re)started so they can continue their work. But there's no "hook" provided by the OS to start *your* app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: I added an afterthought after you already accepted. Hopefully that guides you to an alternative direction that helps you. :) Cheers!